# SaveStateToBundle not called

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am writing an Xamarin Forms application using MVVM Cross. I'm using the Master-Detail presentation model.

I'm attempting to wire up my application to support tombstoning. To do so, I configured my android device so that **Don't Keep Activities = true**. This has the correct desired affect in that when I switch to another application, my application activities are destroyed and when I switch back my application reloads.

However, the methods SaveStateToBundle are never called and subsequently, ReloadFromBundle is never called.  So, I'm stuck on finding a way for my application to restore itself in the tombstoning workflow.

Has anyone had any success doing this?  Complicating matters is that I not only want to remember the state of my detail page, but i also need to remember which detail page was actually loaded.  But at this point I haven't found any way to save my state in the first place.

thanks to all who can help!
Michael